Fetching data simultaneously with Emscripten
I am trying to use Emscripten to fetch and process a set of images. The approach below works well with a single image file, but it fails when fetching multiple images simultaneously, resulting in various errors. I believe the asynchronous fetch operations are sharing resources, which leads to race conditions, data inconsistencies, and other issues. I am using Emscripten's Fetch API to retrieve the images.
How can I solve this problem?
function read_object(object, url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            Module.onFetchClosed = (succeeded) => {
                if (!succeeded) {
                    reject(new Error("Fetch failed"));
                    return;
                };
                resolve();
            };
            object.read_url(url);
        } catch(e) {
            reject(e);
        };
    });
};

var Module = { onRuntimeInitialized: function() {

    async function async_call(n) {
        try {
            var object = new Module.cpp_object();
            let url = await get_url(n);
            await read_object(object, url);
            ...
        } catch(e) {
            object.delete();
            console.error("Error:", e);
        };
    };

    let promises = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
        let promise = async_call(i);
        promises.push(promise)
        console.log(i);
    };
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        ...;
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error("Something went wrong:", err);
    });
}};

I get these errors:
Uncaught RuntimeError: index out of bounds
Error: Object { name: "ExitStatus", message: "Program terminated with exit(1)", status: 1 }

I have tried another approach by modularizing the Emscripten code and giving a Module to each async_call. It works, therefore the C++ code should be okay. However, I don't believe that giving a Module to each async_call is correct.

what is "various errors"? Try to be more precise. tell us more about what you observe (rather than what you believe ;)

The problem is in the C/C++ code compiled with emscripten, not your JavaScript code. If you call it asynchronously, your C/c++ code must be perfectly reentrant. You always call the same thread. You can't create multiple modules, you will always call the same thread.
